# C++11 References variables as lvalues. Are they really "vars" or are only "alias"?

Tags: c++, variables, reference, lvalue

Well, the question is in the title.
If i have the following code in c++11:

```
int a, b = 20;
int &ra = a;
ra = b;
std::cout << ra << std::endl;     //Prints 20
```

how is the "ra" handled by the compiler, does it create another var as a pointer or it's just an alias and when the compiler finds "ra" is the same as saying "a"?

Comment: It can be either. Sometimes compiler can optimize reference variable altogether and just treat it as a name alias, sometimes a variable will be required.

Comment: you cannot tell the difference. Btw variables are also just names used to refer to the actual objects. If you write `const int x = 3;` then there is not necessarily a 3 stored somewhere in memory

Comment: @idclev463035818 Why if we got that const value of 3 it isn't sotored in mem (ram, cache, disk, etc)? It must be stored somewhere!! So how doest the program know about a "3"?

Comment: @Lucas: The program will just say "write 20 to screen". It doesn't need to say "20 is stored over here at position _A_. Now, write the thing at _A_ to screen". So it doesn't / might not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. And, no. Hehe. Read on.

There are two layers of abstraction at work here, and you should try to understand both of them.

### The language

When you write C++, you're describing a program. You're not actually writing instructions for a computer to execute. That's the compiler's job.

In your C++ code, **`ra` is just an alias**. It's not an "object". There is very little syntax to manipulate references, and this is deliberate: we're supposed to treat `ra` as *being* `a`; They're two names for the same thing.

Even when we delve deeper into the language, we can observe this. Given the following function:

```
int bar = 42;

int& foo()
{
   return bar;
}
```

… the expression `foo()` *is not a reference*! This surprises many people. That's an "lvalue of type `int`". Just `int`, not `int&`. It's an expression that "names" the integer that you originally declared using the name `bar`. Conceptually, it's *not* a separate, pointery thing, and the language rules and types and value categories bear that out.

Of course, the fact that `foo()` returns a reference isn't just ignored: it's why no copy is made, and why the resulting expression has the value category *lvalue* instead of *rvalue*.

So, **the reference types don't power the language's ability to refer to objects in multiple places using different expressions**: they only give you, the C++ programmer, access to that ability. References really only pertain to declarations. Once the program has passed your reference declaration, you're not really dealing with references any more, because there isn't really any such thing as "a reference".

*(It is sometimes possible to witness an "abstraction leak" here, though; for example, class members declared with reference type pretty much **have** to take up storage and will be implemented as pointers in every ABI I'm aware of. That's just a practical necessity.)*

### The computer program

By this, I mean the actual computer program created by your compiler. It contains the actual instructions that your target machine will execute.

In this real program, for *any* access, **there may or may not be a dereference of a pointer**, and **there may or may not even be an object stored at some place in memory**. The value may instead just be baked into your code. Some people call this "optimising out", but really it's just your compiler producing the best computer program that has the semantics you've described.

**This applies to non-references as much as to references.** At any decent "optimisation" level, for example, your *entire* real program will probably just be code to send the integer `20` to the `std::cout` machinery; there's no reason for those `int`s to actually "exist" as objects at any memory location during execution, because you never take their address or pass said address on to other translation units that would require them to be "shared" via the magic of the linker.

As such, if you are *really* concerned about performance, you'll need to read the assembly code to find out what is actually happening. Otherwise, you can't and don't need to predict it.

### Putting it all together…

…there's no real reason to worry about whether your reference is an alias or a "variable" in its own right, because that distinction is already blurred completely by the compilation process.